# calling a javascript function from a separate script?

Tags: javascript

I want to organize my JavaScript so I thought I would make a functions `JS` file. Is there anyway I can call the functions from `functions.js` from `global.js`?

---

**EDIT**

`functions.js:`

```
var get_selects;
get_selects = {
    getLanguages: function() {
    }
}
```

`global.js:`

```
get_selects.getLangueges();
```

Comment: If the functions from `functions.js` are global functions, you can call them from `global.js` but make sure that you include the scripts in the correct order: 1. functions.js, 2. global.js. However, I recommend you to **not** define global functions - that just pollutes the global namespace (unnecessarily). A better alternative would be to have one global object - like `PHIL` - and then define those functions as members of that object.

Comment: @coreyward, do you recommend me not having duel scripts?

Comment: haha, I will remember this though! If I were to surround all my javascript inbetween `$(document)ready()` tags would that effect anything with DOM readiness?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, functions defined at the top level are automatically available in the global scope (`window` in a browser), and this is typically not desirable.

Another approach that would mitigate this is to group your functions into a single object so you aren't polluting the global scope with a whole bunch of unrelated functions.

```
var utils;
utils = {
  toast: function(message) {
    alert("Notification: " + message);
  },

  sum: function(a, b){ return a + b; }
}

utils.toast('Email sent');
utils.sum(1, 2);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "using a closure" do you recommend not separating the scripts?

Comment: Okay, a lot of things make more sense, I'm still returning a "undefined" for (in your example) utils.

Comment: Whoops! I had left a stray closing parenthesis in there. I added code for the `its_a_trap` function too so that it's valid (and more fun).

Comment: I apologize, I didn't mean "undefined" i meant "not defined" it can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

If both scripts have been included in the same HTML file, sure, it will work out of the box. Best way to know is to try it.

Answer (score 0):

All .js files load top level functions into the global namespace. So, yes.

Answer (score 0):

simply call it like anyother functions

```
yourFunctionName(yourFunctionParams);
```

be aware, you need to include your functions.js BEFORE your global.js, else it won't see your functions.

Answer (score 0):

From the moment you include a JS in the HTML file, all the functions become available. So, if you make like this, it will work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="global.js"></script>
```

But (as soon as I know), you **must** include "functions.js" first. Otherwise, "global.js" will not be able to find the calls. You can also make a little function inside "global.js" to include "functions.js" on the fly, like this:

```
function include(js_path){
    //By Fabrício Magri e Micox
    //http://elmicox.blogspot.com/2006/12/include-em-javascript.html
    var new= document.createElement('script');
    new.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    new.setAttribute('src', js_path);
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(new);
}
```

Than, on the beginning of your "global.js" you call this function to include the contents of "functions.js" on the  section as soon as the browser requests "global.js"